# Freenode Nick Registration

Tags: irc

I am a newbie when it comes to development.  A friend turned me onto friend as a resource to ask questions.  I am attempting to get my NICK registered, but I can not even get started.  Any input on how to get a NICK registered so I can ask some questions in the forums would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you register your nickname:

1.Pick a nickname, and connect. Make sure you have a nickname that you can remember the next time you log in. If you want to change it after you have connected already, type /nick YourNewNickname

2.Type /msg nickserv register YourPassword you@example.com into the text box of the chat — including the slash at the beginning, and replace the password and email address with something you select.

3.Type /msg nickserv register YourNickName YourPassword

Every time you log in later, you will have to issue the command /msg nickserv register YourNickName YourPassword before we can see what you're typing.

Taken directly from [plone.org](https://plone.org/support/chat/how-to-register).

Comment: You should own the e-mail address, otherwise you can't confirm the nick and the nick will drop in 24h.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't need any further explanation. But you are right